# update mysql table with average column for each day

Tags: mysql

I have a table that consists of 2 columns date, price.  I want to update a column call average.  It will calculate the average of current date and the days before it.

I manage to create a SELECT statement but I'm after an UPDATE statement.

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.price, COUNT(t2.date) AS DAYS, AVG(t2.price) AS avgprice
FROM PriceTable AS t1, PriceTable AS t2
WHERE t1.date >= t2.date
GROUP BY t1.date
```

Here's a link of what I want it to look like: http://pastebin.com/t7PMz4Jc

Thanks

Comment: update table set col=(select Avg(t2.price) from pricetab t1, pricetab t2 where t1.pricetab>t2.pricetab group by ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way (using multi-table syntax)

```sql
UPDATE PriceTable p JOIN
(
  SELECT t1.date, AVG(t2.price) avgprice
    FROM PriceTable t1 JOIN PriceTable t2
      ON t1.date >= t2.date
   GROUP BY t1.date
) s 
    ON p.date = s.date
   SET p.avgprice = s.avgprice;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd6cb/1)** demo

or (using a subquery)

```sql
UPDATE PriceTable p
   SET p.avgprice = 
(
  SELECT AVG(price)
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT * 
      FROM PriceTable 
  ) q
   WHERE date <= p.date
);
```

**Note:** that when you use a subquery you have to hide the target table from MySQL by wrapping it in an additional select. If don't do that you'll get an error message

> You can't specify target table `<table_name>` for update in FROM clause

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43606/1)** demo